# Switching values within a row

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a few rows.

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  y1   y2   y3   y4   y5
1   3   2   1   5  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.4  0.2
1   2   4   2   4   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
4   4   1   2   4  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.9
```

`-1` is really just an arbitrary value that symbolizes the absence of something.

I want to switch the `-1` from being in the `y` columns to be in the `x` columns:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  y1   y2   y3   y4   y5
 1   3   2   1   5  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.4  0.2
-1  -1  -1  -1  -1  1    2    4    2    4   ###Changed row
 4   4   1   2   4  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.9
```

This is just an example dataset; the thing is that I have more than 30 datasets, each with 1,000+ lines of data where this kind of thing happens in several places. I know there's a way you can do it by just chopping up the whole dataset and the switching the values around, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to handle it in large datasets, such as with a for loop?

Comment: do you only have 2 different (x, y) set of columns in each set?

Comment: Having numbered columns like this makes most operations harder. You should probably reshape your data frame into long format (look up the ‹tidyr› package). This makes this operation trivial.

Comment: Under certain circumstances, that fit this example, you could use `df[df$y1 < 0,] <- df[df$y1 < 0, c(6:10, 1:5)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution:

```
library(dplyr)

#Example dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  matrix(round(runif(15,min = 0,max=5),digits = 0),ncol = 5),
  matrix(round(runif(15,min = 0,max=1),digits = 1),ncol = 5,dimnames = list(NULL,paste0('y',1:5)))
)
df[2,6:10] <- -1

switcher_function <- function(d){
  d <- data.frame(t(d))
  df.y <- d %>% select(contains('y'))
  df.x <- d %>% select(contains('x'))
  if(sum(df.y)==-1*ncol(df.y)){
    return(as.numeric(cbind(df.y[1,],df.x[1,])))
  }else{
    return(as.numeric(cbind(df.x[1,],df.y[1,])))
  }
}

want <- t(apply(X = df,MARGIN = 1,FUN = switcher_function))
```

Comment: should be `df[2,6:10] <- -1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using base R, given that you only have 2 different sets of columns (x and y), then,

```
ind1 <- t(apply(df2, 1, function(i)mapply(function(x, y) 
           replace(x, all(y == -1), y), i[grepl('x', names(i))], i[grepl('y', names(i))])))

 ind2 <- t(apply(df2, 1, function(i)mapply(function(x, y) 
           replace(x, all(x == -1), y), i[grepl('y', names(i))], i[grepl('x', names(i))])))

final_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ind1, ind2))

final_df
#   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5  y1  y2  y3  y4  y5
#1  1  3  2  1  5 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.4 0.2
#2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1.0 2.0 4.0 2.0 4.0
#3  4  4  1  2  4 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

[In tidy data format](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), your table would look as follows:

```
       i     x     y
1      1     1   0.2
2      1     1  -1.0
3      1     4   0.2
4      2     3   0.1
5      2     2  -1.0
6      2     4   0.2
7      3     2   0.1
8      3     4  -1.0
9      3     1   0.3
10     4     1   0.4
11     4     2  -1.0
12     4     2   0.1
13     5     5   0.2
14     5     4  -1.0
15     5     4   0.9
```

Given in this format, it’s trivial (…) to swap cells where the `y` is negative:

```
mutate_when(df, y < 0, x = y, y = x)
```

This uses a ‹dplyr› extension (`mutate_when`) with [its code available as a Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/klmr/41326eae65642efa6d22b9b9b1358452).

Alternatively you can do the same using just ‹dplyr› and ‹tibble›, but it’s a bit more complicated:

```
do(tibble(x = ifelse(.$y < 0, .$y, .$x),
          y = ifelse(.$y < 0, .$x, .$y),
          i = .$i))
```

This is using the `tibble` from the package of the same name, and `do` from ‹dplyr›. There might be an even better way — I just don’t know it.

… but getting your table into tidy format and, after the transformation, back out of tidy format is a bit more complex. Here’s the transformation into tidy data:

```
tidy_df = df %>%
    gather(name, value) %>%
    mutate(i = as.integer(sub('x|y', '', name)),
           name = sub('\\d', '', name)) %>%
    group_by(name, i) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    spread(name, value)
```

(This adds an extra column to preserve the row index in your original table to transform it back afterwards. If that’s not needed, then neither is the index.)

Now we can perform the swapping …

```
tidy_df_swapped = tidy_df %>%
    mutate_when(y < 0, x = y, y = x)
```

After which the transformation back looks like this:

```
df_swapped = tidy_df_swapped %>%
    gather(name, value, -i, -row) %>%
    mutate(name = paste0(name, i)) %>%
    select(-i) %>%
    spread(name, value) %>%
    select(-row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a matrix solution as it wasn't specified how the data will be stored.  I also changed the `-1` to `NA` since it was stated that was an arbitrary selection

```
m1 <- structure(c(1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 0.2, NA, 0.2, 0.1, NA, 0.2, 0.1, NA, 0.3, 0.4, 2, NA, 0.2, NA, NA),
                .Dim = c(3L, 10L),
                .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5")))

ind <- is.na(m1[, paste0("y", 1:5)])
m1[ind] <- c(tail(m1[ind], length(m1[ind])/2), head(m1[ind], length(m1[ind])/2))
```

To provide some speed comparisons (and save microseconds!)

```
Unit: microseconds
               min        lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
  matrix    47.940   64.8710   89.9407   86.939   98.734   165.126   100
final_df   704.258  742.3055  986.9160  791.767 1057.909  4310.011   100
    want  3647.605 3982.4225 5184.6407 4410.836 6450.177 15161.132   100
```

There might be a more elegant way to swap the array in the second step, but it's what I got for now.